# Create action when I click on a button than UIAlertcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

i Create two buttons of `UIAlertcontroller`:

```
One Button - "OpenCamera"
Two button - "OpenGallery"
```

I just can not understand how I create action when I click on one of them.

```
- (IBAction)takePic:(id)sender {


UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet]; // 1
UIAlertAction *openCamrea = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open camrea"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                      }];
UIAlertAction *openGallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open gallery"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       }];

[alert addAction:openCamrea];
[alert addAction:openGallery];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: `handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {//Code what to do when button is pressed}];`? Or is that you don't know how to open camera or how to open gallery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handler is the block to be executed on the selection of the item.

```
UIAlertAction *openGallery = [UIAlertAction
    actionWithTitle:@"open gallery"
    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        // Code to run when the open gallery option is pressed.
    }];
```

BTW I think the long unbroken lines in the question really don't help as they effectively hide the key parameter.

Comment: Works perfect!

Thank you.

Comment: Is nobody experiencing significant delays for the code inside the handler? It feels slow compared to UIAlertView, since the alert view did not wait for the animation to complete entirely. I really don't like this, but it seems there's no other way.

Comment: @nickdnk Do you mean if the button is pressed before the animation is complete? You could select no animation and it may also be possible to customise the animation via the UIPresentationController but you are moving onto completely different questions at that point.

Comment: I mean the delay from when you click the alert button and the completion block runs. It waits around 6-700ms because it needs to actually dismiss a view controller. Setting animated to NO makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

**The complete code:**

```
- (IBAction)takePic:(id)sender {


  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

  UIAlertAction *openCamrea = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open camrea"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
  {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"message:@"Device has no camera"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];
    }
    else
    {
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       picker.delegate = self;
       picker.allowsEditing = YES;
       picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

       [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
  }];
  UIAlertAction *openGallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open gallery"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
  {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }];

  [alert addAction:openCamrea];
  [alert addAction:openGallery];

  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  self.img.image = chosenImage;

  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside the `handler` blocks you are passing to `[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:style:handler:]`

For example:

```
UIAlertAction *openCamrea = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open camrea"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                          // openCamera action code goes here

                                                  }];

UIAlertAction *openGallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"open gallery"
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                       // openGallery action code goes here

                                                   }];
```